# Error in syntax - going nuts

Tags: python

[stupid syntax error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfBhP.jpg)

I can't quite figure out what the problem is with this little bit of code. It works fine if I have it print "x is the highest odd number", but whenever I try to get it to print the actual value of 'x', I get a syntax error.  What small, simple step am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet that is failing?

Comment: What's this mess ? Your OS don't have a screen capture application ? oO Or better, just copy & paste text...

Comment: Hi Brent, please include more details about your question. I suggest add "Python" into the question title would help. For your situation you need `print((x) + ' is the highest odd number.')` Another way(string formatting) to do it is `print('%s is the highest odd number' % x)`

Comment: Why not copy and paste your code?  rather than take a photo!

Comment: Or he could have just pasted the code in his post.

Comment: @VKen, adding "Python" to the title helps very little for SO users. Our searches and tags rely on the tags set in the question. "Python" in the title would only help searches outside SO.

Comment: @theTinMan searches outside SO would have access to the python tag, so it won't even help them (surely?)

Comment: Note that your code will also fail if x > y, but z is greater than both of them . . . you can't just compare the numbers in pairs, but you need to compare all three against each other . . ..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print x, 'is the highest odd number'
```

Or if you're using Python 3:

```
print(x, 'is the highest odd number')
```

Comment: That's Python 2. Judging from the parentheses on the `print` calls in OP's code, it's Python 3.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll have to keep in mind to actually use a screen cap or post the area where I'm having an issue, instead of cell phone pictures.

Comment: @delnan python 2+ also allows for the parantheses syntax with print - I was thinking he was coming from another language, not python 3.  For completeness, the answer should probably include .format() and % formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
 print(x, "is the highest odd number")
```

Is the [python3 syntax for print](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#print).

Without the comma:

```
x "is the highest odd number"
```

is a number and a string next to each other without an operator, hence the syntax error.

*Similarly, evaluating `2"a"` will give you a syntax error.*